# How to add multiple links one under the other after input in convert box

Tags: javascript, html

I've encountered some issues with a code.

```js
function convert()
    {
      var text=document.getElementById("url").value;
      var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
      var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
      document.getElementById("converted_url1").innerHTML=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');


    }
```

```html
 <textarea id="url" rows="3" cols="50">https://www.example.org
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convert();">
 <p id="converted_url1"></p>
```

So, after input, it adds the link below, but I'd like to be able to add links one under the other, not a single one. I am lost, any ideas? Thank you a lot :D (I'm still learning, please don't hate)

Comment: Could you show us some examples and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only able to add one link because you are replacing the existing html inside `converted_url1` with the newly generated html every time. Instead you want to be creating a new DOM Node and appending it to the document. This can be done many ways, one of which is to assign your new html to another DOM Node (typically one not on the page) and plucking the new content out. Seen below:

```js
function convert()
    {
      var text=document.getElementById("url").value;
      var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
      var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
      
      var template = document.createElement('template');
      template.innerHTML = text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
      document.getElementById("converted_url1").appendChild(template.content);


    }
```

```html
<textarea id="url" Placeholder="Enter Some Text With Links">
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convert();">
 <p id="converted_url1"></p>
```

Other approaches can have you just create the link, and assign it's properties to the desired values (as opposed to using an HTML string as in approach one). Just to demonstrate the syntax:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "http://somedomain.com";
document.getElementById('somecontainer').appendChild(link);
```

Comment: this solved it. OMG, i totally forgot about DOM nodes. I'm silly. Thank you a lot, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Don't just set the `innerHTML` of the one `<p>` tag, instead create a new element each time and append that new element into your output holder.

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('#url');
var outputEl = document.querySelector('#converted_url1');
var convertBtn = document.querySelector('#converter');

function convert() {
  var text = textarea.value;
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  var text1 = text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
  var exp2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  var newP = document.createElement('p');
  newP.innerHTML=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
  outputEl.append(newP);
}

convertBtn.addEventListener('click', convert);
```

```html
<textarea id="url" Placeholder="Enter Some Text With Links"></textarea><br/>
<input id="converter" type="button" value="Convert">
<div id="converted_url1"></div>
```

innerHTML` on one element. Instead create a new element each time:

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a div:  `<div><a href='$1'>$1</a></div>`. Div has a `display:block` by default, so it will be located under the previous block element.

```js
function convert()
    {
      var text=document.getElementById("url").value;
      var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      var text1=text.replace(exp, "<div><a href='$1'>$1</a></div>");
      var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
      document.getElementById("converted_url1").innerHTML+=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');


    }
```

```html
<textarea id="url" rows="3" cols="50">https://www.example1.org
https://www.example2.org
https://www.example3.org
https://www.example4.org
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convert();">
 <p id="converted_url1"></p>
```

Comment: Good approach. I would just add a plus symbol on the fifth line:
`document.getElementById("converted_url1").innerHTML += text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');`